# Creating a dropdown toolbar in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've recently started working with XAML in WPF and I'm working on someone elses code. I'm trying to rework a drop down toolbar/menu, because of some display issues but the drop down is created as a `<Popup>`. I feel technically a menu is not really a popup...

So my question is, is it appropriate to ever create sub/drop down menus using the popup tag? Or would it be better suited for `<stackPanel>` or something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already stated, you could use a ComboBox and make it look like a drop down menu. You could use a Popup to make it look like drop down menu either. Both require quite some template work but I wouldn't have anything against it as long as it looks as you want it to look.

For a classic menu & drop down I would just use the Menu control. [Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/menu-control/) some information about it. Depending on your situation, it's probably just an easier way to get the same result

Code from site:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Common_interface_controls.MenuSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MenuSample" Height="200" Width="200">
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: so using a Popup for menus is an appropriate choice? I suppose I ask coming from a HTML background where some elements just aren't suitable for certain functions, so wasn't sure to the extent of that with XAML

Comment: I don't know the situation but generally I woudn't call it "appropriate" either. I suppose the Menu control had some limitations so he decided to use a Popup instead. As you may think, the uses of a popup are more like [that](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/popup/page/2/) .

Comment: yeah for sure, ok that's great thanks for the quick overview!